# Retrieve all values from child i collectionView

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview, indexpath

I´m trying to retrieve all the values from one child into a collectionView

I keep getting this error

Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' in this line

```
let follower = snapshotValue!["Followers"] as! String
```

here is my code

```
followRef.child("users").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.displayName)!).observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: {
            snapshot in
            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
            let follower = snapshotValue!["Followers"] as! String
            self.postsFollow.insert(postFollowStruct(follower: follower) , at: 0)
            self.followersView.reloadData()
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

By what i understand you have many json objects in your snapshot.value? Then you want to cast to an object each one of them and put them into an array?

```
if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                    let followers = dict
                    for follower in followers {
                        if let restDict = follower.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                            let followerObj = Follower()
                            followerObj.setValuesForKeys(restDict)
                            //add to array
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: @CarstenHøvsgaard, Its a Class Object. Follower() is the way to instantiate it. Then calling setValuesForKeys(restDict) Will apply the values to its properties. If restDict has key "Name" with value "Carsten", then followerObj will have those values. You must have properties "Name" in your class or it will crash. Then you provide that object to your collectionView. If thats what you want to do.